# Solve in $\mathbb{N}$ the system: $x²-y²=5440$ and $ x \land y = 8$

Tags: arithmetic

We have:

$$x^{2}-y^{2} = (x-y)(x+y) = 5440 = 2^6\cdot 5\cdot 17$$

$$x \land y = 8.$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $x \land y$ in body and $x \cap y$ in title?

Comment: What do you mean by $x\wedge y$? The minimum of $x$ and $y$? You can sort out, as you did, divisors, and then decide what solutions to discard.

Comment: @DHMO Keep the language PG-13, please.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Greatest common divisor.

Comment: @Jacob. We say $(x,y)$ for that.

Comment: Wow.  $x\wedge y=8$ means $\gcd (x,y)=8$?   I'm sure I'm not the only one who will say he's never seem that and would never have guessed it's meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=8a$ and $y=8b$, where $a \perp b$.

Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(x-y)(x+y) &=& 2^6 \times 5 \times 17 \\
(8a-8b)(8a+8b) &=& 2^6 \times 5 \times 17 \\
(a-b)(a+b) &=& 5 \times 17 \\
\end{array}$$

Case one:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\begin{cases}a-b&=&1\\a+b&=&85\end{cases} \\
\implies&\begin{cases}a&=&43\\b&=&42\end{cases} \\
\implies&\begin{cases}x&=&344\\y&=&336\end{cases}
\end{array}$$

Case two:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\begin{cases}a-b&=&5\\a+b&=&17\end{cases} \\
\implies&\begin{cases}a&=&11\\b&=&6\end{cases} \\
\implies&\begin{cases}x&=&88\\y&=&48\end{cases}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

As $\gcd (x,y)=8$ then you know $x =8x'$ and $y=8y'$ and $x^2-y^2=64 (x'^2-y'^2)=5440$

So $(x'^2-y'^2)=(x'-y')(x'+y')=85=5*17$

As $x'+y'$ is positive, then $x'-y'$ is positive so $x'>y'$ and $x'+y' > x'-y'$

The only ways to factor $85$ is either:

1)  $x'+y'= 85;x'-y'=1$

Or

2) $x'+y'=17;x'-y'=5$

1) yields $y'=42;x'=43$ and $x=43*8=344;y=42*8=336 $

2) yields $y'=6;x'=11;x=88;y=48$

Answer (score 0):

$$gcd(x,y) = 8$$

So $x = 8u$, $y = 8v$, so

$$(8u)^2 - (8v)^2 = 5440$$
$$u^2 - v^2 = 85$$
$$(u + v)(u - v) = 17 \times 5$$
or 
$$(u + v)(u - v) = 85 \times 1$$